# Reverse Characteristic Function of the Cantor Set

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

Let $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$

$f(x) = 0$ if $x\in C$

$f(x) = 1$ otherwise

Show that $f$ is Riemann Integrable and compute
$$\int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$$

I called this the "reverse" characteristic function since normally the $1$ and $0$ have their places switched. When I did this problem, I thought the answer was the same as the normal characteristic function.
We want to show $U(f) = L(f) = \int_{0}^{1} f(x) dx$
Let $P$ be a partition
First, notice that $L(f,P) = 0$ because there are points in $[0,1]$ that are in the Cantor set.
This means $L(f) = 0$

Now, $U(f,P) = \frac{2^n}{3^n}$ since this is the length of the nth subinterval and the supremum is $1$ due to their being points in $[0,1]$ that are not in the Cantor set.
Taking the infimum on both sides,
$U(f) = inf (U(f,P)) = inf \frac{2^n}{3^n} = 0$ because as $n \to \infty$, this expression goes to $0$.
Therefore, the function is RI since $U(f) = L(f)$ and the value is $0$.

However, my classmates have told me that the answer is $1$. My professor neither confirmed nor denied this, but he did say that my answer was wrong. Considering that the normal characteristic function has a value of $0$ for this problem, it would make sense that this version has $1$ as an answer. However, I do not see how.

Can anyone explain this and show the steps?

Thank you!

Comment: Count the length-$3^{-n}$ intervals in $C$'s complement.

Comment: You never define $n$, so when you say $U(f,P)=\frac{2^n}{3^n}$ it's not clear what you mean. If you're suggesting that that's the proportion of points _not_ in the $n$th level of the Cantor set, then I think you have your math backwards.

Comment: It is not true that $L(f,P) = 0$. For example, if $P$ contains points $x_i, x_{i+1} \in (1/3,2/3)$, then $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [x_i,x_{i+1}]$. Have you already computed the integral of the characteristic function of $C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g$ is the characteristic function of $C$ the $f(x)=1-g(x)$ for all $x$. Hence, $\int_0^{1} f(x)dx=\int_0^{1} 1dx-\int_0^{1} g(x)dx=1-0=1$,

Comment: Wow, I did not even think of this... it was that simple...

Comment: Hey bad news, I was actually just told by my instructor that this answer is wrong. I already accepted it, but my instructor said that the characteristic function g is actually NOT RI in this sense, which I am highly doubting because there are so many answers on it. But nevertheless, he said so.

Comment: @DominicBlanco Your instructor is wrong. A bounded function is RI iff it is continuous almost everywhere. $d$ is continuous at all points in the intervals that are removed in the construction of $C$. Hence it is continuous almost everywhere. Your instructor can object to the use the theorem I quoted here but my answer is not wrong.

Comment: I believe he is wrong as well, but he is insistent. I can't seem to convince him otherwise.